# how to implement unittest.skip from python 3.1 in python 2.6?

Tags: python, unit-testing

do you know of any implementation of unittest.skip of python 3.1 in python 2.6/2.7?
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try installing the [unittest2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) package, "a backport of the new features added to the unittest testing framework" in Python 2.7 and 3.2.

Comment: Good!  By the way, if the answer is acceptable, you should mark it as accepted so that the responder (me!) gets reputation points for it.  If not, you should edit your question or leave comments until you do get an acceptable answer.